# Angular Interpolation Only Accepting 1 specific paramter

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.0 and I've come across something that I cannot figure out despite a lot of google-ing and debugging.

If I define a controller and inject the `$interpolate` provider, I can use the following code to get some dynamic output;

```
var x = $interpolate('Hello {{name}}!');
```

Calling `x({});` will output `Hello !`
Calling `x({name: 'FizzBuzz'});` will output `Hello FizzBuzz!`

However, if I then try to set it to a different variable;

```
var z = $interpolate('Hello {{abc}}!');
```

It immediately gives this error;

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function
```

It's almost like `$interpolate` can only be set once. Really confused, please help.

**EDIT:** This appears to be an issue with Chrome Developer Tools. If I break after the line that defines the interpolation call (i.e. `var x = $interpolate(...)`) and try to do a new call like `var y = $interpolate(...)` then that's where everything falls down and I get the Uncaught Type Error.

Comment: Are you sure you example code is correct? x({'FizzBuzz'}) shouldn't work, as it needs a property name. Can you provide a workable example in something like plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah sorry, updated the example calls. I'm not sure how to do the injection part in jsfiddle...otherwise I'd happily do so. I've just noted this via chrome dev tools / console too. Not 100% sure how to replicate that in jsfiddle either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this should work.

```
var x = $interpolate('Hello {{abc}}!');

x({abc: 'FizzBuzz'});
```

Ref : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate

Comment: Err, apologies, that's what I meant, I typed it out too fast (edited now). The initial setting of interpolate is fine, it's when you try to change the string that it seems to fall down.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/prasanthbendra/qz5xbkn5/ is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be something weird with Chrome Dev Tools console when debugging. That jsfiddle works fine though.